# Retracting a Shaft into a bushing

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I need to pull a shaft longitudinally into a bushing. There is no rotation involved. It will be pulled against a spring load. I need it to be manually retracted about .200" it will release if the actuator (mechanical) is released. Previous versions used a lever that contacted the shaft in a cut out section of the shaft., but this reduced the stiffness of the shaft. The ends of the shaft are both being used and are not available for the mechanism. I have thought about a magnetic retractor, but not sure how. The entire shaft and bushing assembly are about 2"-2.5" long and I cant use too much more space than that. anyone have any experience with this kind of thing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A solenoid is a steel (magnetic) shaft surrounded by a coil of wire. There is typically a spring placing tension in one direction on the shaft. When the coil is energized, the magnetic field will pull the shaft into the coil. Some of the shaft must be enclosed by the coil, perhaps all of it for the height of the coil in order to have maximum force applied to the shaft.

I've not seen a solenoid used with the shaft placed much deeper on the coil than at the end, but I suspect that the coil must be offset from the half-way point in order to move the shaft.

You could conceivably place the coil at 0.200 inches from the center. When the coil is energized, you would have that much movement. Alternatively, a mechanical stop on the system, akin to a drill bit depth stop would provide a limiting force.